# c# deserialize objects issue

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

This is my input XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hosts>
  <host>
    <hostId>239|BS|OWN</hostId>
    <images>
      <image>
        <name>Pic.jpg</name>
        <main>true</main>
        <source>../Images/Melissa/Pic.jpg</source>
      </image>
    </images>
  </host>
</hosts>
```

and this is my class used to deserialiaze that XML file:

```
[XmlRoot("hosts")]
public class hosts
{
    [XmlElement("host")]       
    public List<Host> Listehosts { get; set; }
}


public class Host
{
    [XmlElement("hostId")]
    public string hostId { get; set; }              

    [XmlElement("images")]
    public List<Image> Listeimages { get; set; }
}


public class Image
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("main")]
    public string main { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("source")]
    public string source { get; set; }      
}
```

And this the code of my main program:

```
string outputTmp = "Images.xml";
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(hosts));
TextReader reader = new StreamReader(outputTmp);
object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
hosts XmlData = (hosts)obj;
reader.Close();            
Console.WriteLine(XmlData.Listehosts.Count);
```

The problem is that always images list are empty when I execute my program.
The list of hosts is charged correctly but when I checked the list of image it contains permanently null value for all the attribute (`name`, `main`, `source`).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
    public class Host
    {
         [XmlElement("hostId")]
         public string hostId { get; set; }              

         [XmlArray("images")] // CHANGED
         [XmlArrayItem("image", typeof(Image))] // CHANGED
         public List<Image> Listeimages { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake in your code, add an ImageCollection class with a list inside.

```
public class ImageCollection
{
    [XmlElement("image")]  
    public List<Image> Listeimages { get; set; }
}

public class Host
{
     [XmlElement("hostId")]
     public string hostId { get; set; }              

     [XmlElement("images")]
     public ImageCollection ImageCollection { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: HI Sepehr Farshid , that's method is also working thank you a lot for identifing my mistake.